# h5py writing array in compound type

Tags: arrays, nested, hdf5, h5py

### Stocking array or nested array in this compound type

*I'm slowly discovering this library and I can't find any clue or solution to create array or nested array*

```py
hdfs = h5py.File('12346NUL.h5', 'w')

utf8 = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8')
bstr = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str) # old method to create VL string

dt  = np.dtype([("id", utf8),
                ("events", bstr), 
                ("level1", utf8),
                ("level2", utf8),
                ("level3", utf8),
                ("lecture", np.int32),
                ("iso639", utf8),
                ("domains", utf8)])


metadata = hdfs.create_dataset("metadata", (10,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=dt)

metadata[1] = ('bpt6k619227', '1739','text', 'print monograph', 'map', 319, 'fre', 'public domains')

hdfs.close()
```

*For `events` I would like to be able to write*

```py
('bpt6k619227', ['1739','1233-12','1234-12-06'], 'text', 'print monograph', 'map', 319, 'fre', 'public domains')
```

*or even nested list like this:*

```py
('bpt6k619227', ['1739','1233-12',['1234','1555'],'1234-12-06'], 'text', 'printed monograph', 'map', 319, 'fre', 'public domains')
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `metadata[1]` assignment works?  Looks like you define `events` field as a variable length string.  In `numpy` use that has to be a defined length, e.g. `U10`.  I'm not quite sure how `h5py` handles that.  But in your desired lines, `events` looks like a list of arbitrary complexity.  In a numpy array that would have to be an `object` dtype field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first requested example (a list of names) is straightforward (if it has a known/fixed size). The key is modifying your dataset `dtype` definition appropriately. If you want a field to be an array of elements, you specify the array dtype and shape you want. For your `events` field, it would look something like this: `('events', utf8, (3,))`. (It's possible to have a variable length array. See the 2nd example.)

[The nested list of lists is more complicated. I'm not sure if/how it can be done. Since h5py uses numpy dtypes to define the fields, create the`np.dtype()` and see what h5py says.]

Side note: you used 2 different methods to create a VL string dtype: `utf8 = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8')` and `bstr = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)`. You should use `h5py.string_dtype()`. It was added to h5py 2.10. Prior to that, `h5py.special_dtype()` was used to create the VL string dtype (along with other special types).

Here is your example modified to load `events` as an array of 3 variable length strings. (For simplicity, I reduced the number of fields.) I prefer to use Python's `with/as` context manager to open files. And, I changed the variable named `utf8` to `vl_str_dt`.

```
with h5py.File('test_vlstr_arr.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    nrows, str_a0  = 10, 3
    vl_str_dt = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8')
    ds_dt = np.dtype([('id', vl_str_dt),  ('events_arr', vl_str_dt, (str_a0,)), ('lecture', int)])
    
    ds = h5f.create_dataset('metadata',shape=(nrows,), dtype=ds_dt)
    
    id_list = ['bpt6k619227', 'lpp6q9019227', 'xyz7mj719227' ]

    events_arr_list = [np.array(['1739',  '1233-12', '1234-12-06']),
                       np.array(['18812', '12333-12','4321-122-106']),
                       np.array(['198766','12344-12','102340-102-006']) ]

    for i in range(len(id_list)):
        ds[i] = (id_list[i], events_arr_list [i], i)
    
    print(ds.dtype,'\n')
    print(ds[:len(id_list)])
```

The 2nd example shows how to create the "events" field (column) as a variable length array (a "ragged array") of variable length strings. There is small change to the dtype definitions. You declare the variable length array with `h5py.vlen_dtype(basetype)`, where `basetype` is `vl_str_dt` -- your VL string dtype. There is also a small modification to create each "event" array before loading to the dataset. Finally, to demonstrate the VL array behavior, that I modified the events data to have a different number of events for each row: (3, 2, 4).

```
with h5py.File('test_vlstr_vlarr.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    nrows, str_a0  = 10, 3
    vl_str_dt = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8')
    vl_str_arr_dt = h5py.vlen_dtype(vl_str_dt) ## added for events VL array
    
    ds_dt = np.dtype([('id', vl_str_dt),  ('events_arr', vl_str_arr_dt), ('lecture', int)])
    
    ds = h5f.create_dataset('metadata',shape=(nrows,),dtype=ds_dt)
    
    id_list = ['bpt6k619227', 'lpp6q9019227', 'xyz7mj719227' ]

    event_list = [['1739',  '1233-12', '1234-12-06'],
                  ['18812', '12333-12'],
                  ['198766','12344-12','4321-122-106','102340-102-006']]

    for i in range(len(id_list)):
        event_arr = np.array(event_list[i]).astype(vl_str_dt)
        ds[i] = (id_list[i], event_arr, i)
    
    print(ds.dtype,'\n')
    print(ds[:len(id_list)])
```

Comment: Thank you, for all this information! The last thing I wonder, if I don't know the shape of the array in advance? I saw that when you `create_dataset` you can specify shape=(None,)

Comment: When you say "shape of array" are you referring to the text array for `events` or the array that represents the entire dataset?

Comment: yes i'm referring to the array for events `(str_a0,)`

Comment: To clarify, setting `shape=(None,)` in `create_dataset()` creates an empty (or null) dataset. They not are intended to stored data, just attributes. Apparently it was done for netCDF-4 implementation.

Comment: If you don't know how many events you will have for each row, you can create the `events` field (column) as a variable length (aka “ragged”) **_array_** of variable length **_strings_**.  I will add a 2nd example that shows how to do this to my previous answer.

Comment: Thank you for all this information I really appreciate your demonstration !